# Angularjs :$routeChangeStart event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm newbie in angularjs how can check if user logged? i'm using sailsjs backend and angularjs front end

```
module.run(function ($location, $rootScope) {
      $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {

      });
   })
```

**signin.js**

```
.controller('SigninCtrl', function ($scope,$location,User,$http) {             


    $scope.signin = function(){
    var data={ email:$scope.email,password:$scope.password}
       var user=User.signin(data);
        //console.log(typeof user);
     user.success(function (data) {
                    //console.log("token signin",data);
                    var token=data.token;
                localStorage.setItem('id_token', token);
                    $location.path("/todo");
               })
               .error(function (data) {
                    //Do whatever is needed
                 //console.log(data);
               });  
        }   

  });
```

**service :User.js**
    signin: function(data){

```
            return $sails.post('/api/auth',data);
        },
```

Comment: First of all, to improve your code you will want to abstract the sign in logic to it's own factory.

Comment: @CallumLinington how ? can u give me example ?

Comment: working on it, give me a min

Answer (score 0):

Right, I have done something fairly straightforward. See this [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/0ORKJYjnTDEXthC5xthx?p=preview) for more details.

`userHttpService` would normally wrap `$http` but as I haven't got an endpoint to actually hit I'm faking out a promise using the `$q` library.

`routeConfig` is a provider which you can set up at config time to configure with routes that you are allowed to go to. If you use something like [ui router](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router) you can do something far more elegant with a `settings` object on the route setup. If you want to see something far more elegant and advanced, look at this [repo](https://github.com/clinington/shopping).

The config goes as so:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, routeConfigProvider) {

  $routeProvider.when('/home', { template: '<h2>Home</h2><p>Please do something</p>' })
  $routeProvider.when('/login', { controller: 'LoginController', template: '<h2>Login</h2><div><p><span>Name:</span><input type="text" ng-model="name" /></p><p><span>Password:</span><input type="password" ng-model="password" /></p></div><div><p><button type="submit" ng-click="login()">Login</button></p></div><div><p>{{error}}</p></div>' });
  $routeProvider.when('/profile', { controller: 'ProfileController', template: '<h2>Profile</h2><div><p><span>Name:</span>{{name}}</p></div>' });

  $routeProvider.otherwise('/home');

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);


  routeConfigProvider.addRouteWhenLoggedIn('/profile');
  routeConfigProvider.addRouteWhenLoggedIn('/home');

  routeConfigProvider.addRouteWhenLoggedOut('/home');
  routeConfigProvider.addRouteWhenLoggedOut('/login');
});
```

I just bundled all my templates into there for my own ease of use. I pull in my `routeConfigProvider` (note that you don't add `Provider` when you name it `.provider('routeConfig', ...`, angular does that for you).

Then I go about adding routes to the different tables, one table are for routes you are allowed to navigate to when you're logged in, and the other, for routes you are allowed to navigate to when you're logged out.

Below is where you actually act on the route navigation.

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, routeConfig, userService) {
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (e, c, p) {
    var topath = c.$$route.originalPath;

    if (userService.isLoggedIn()) {
      if (!routeConfig.isAllowedWhenLoggedIn(topath)){
        e.preventDefault();
        // you can use $location.path to redirect if you wish
      }
    } else {
      if (!routeConfig.isAllowedWhenLoggedOut(topath)){
        e.preventDefault();
        // you can use $location.path to redirect if you wish
      }
    }
  });
});
```

It is pretty simple, it uses the `userService` (remember it's not the `userHttpService` so this has the responsibility of dishing out user specific things) and asks it whether the user is logged in. Then it will look up either route table to see if they're allowed to navigate to the route.

The `e.PreventDefault()` is how you prevent navigation.